# MySql - Sum data from Table, with aggregated data from sub-tables - performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, join

i have the following query

```
select q.has_content_violation, 
  if(q.max_finding_status = 1, 1, 
    if(q.min_finding_status >=3, 3, 2)) scan_item_finding_status,  
  count(*)
from (
    SELECT si.id, if(f.id is not null, true, false) has_content_violation, 
        min(f.finding_status) min_finding_status, 
        max(f.finding_status) max_finding_status
    FROM bank b
    JOIN merchant m ON m.bank_id = b.id
    JOIN merchant_has_scan ms ON m.last_scan_completed_id = ms.id
    JOIN scan_item si ON si.merchant_has_scan_id = ms.id
    LEFT JOIN finding f ON f.scan_item_id = si.id
    WHERE f.finding_type = 1
    GROUP BY si.id
    ) q
GROUP BY scan_item_finding_status, q.has_content_violation
```

the query takes data from table `finding` and agregate it for scan item, finding if it has several key parameters like `finding_type=1` and using the `left join` to find if the `scan_item` has `findings` in the sub-table with `finding_type=1`.
after that the outer query takes the agregated data and sums it up by some columns.
the query works great but the outer query is not using indexes and doing a full-table search.
Is there a way to make the outer query run better and use indexes? this query is going to run on 10,000 rows each run and will run all day, so it is most important that it will be as fast as possible

Comment: Why are you using a left join with a non-null predicate?

Comment: i'm using the left join to find all the 'scan_item' that has no 'finding' below them with 'finding_type' 1

Comment: No - the predicate removes these rows. Still not clear what you are trying to achieve, but it sounds like the query is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Which joins are many:many; which are 1:many; which are many:1.  The performance probably may stem from the inflate (due to `JOIN`) followed by deflate (due to `GROUP BY`).  We need to find a way to avoid such.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames i did an EXPLAIN on the query to see what is using index and what isn't. all the inner query is using index. all the joins are 1:many but the merchant_has_scan (1:1) - there are many merchant to bank, there are many scan_item to merchant_has_scan and there are many finding to scan_item. all using index

Comment: @symcbean can you explain what do you mean by that? testing the query shows the result i need as i wanted, the left joins make it so i get null when there are finding with finding_type not 1, and then i sum them. i might not understood your comment